# Appium получить текст блока

Tags: python-2.7, appium

Доброго дня!
Есть тест на Appium. Он набирает в поиске "Москва" и кликает на первый элемент:

```
from aapium import WebDriver
....
a = list(self.driver.find_elements_by_id('com.mapswithme.maps.pro:id/recycler'))
```

Элементы находятся (т.е. если я введу команду a[0].click() , нажмется первый элемент).

[image: Appium]

Но я никак не могу получить оттуда текст (Москва, Город и т.д.)
a[0].text возвращает пустой массив, a[0].get_attribute['text'] тоже

Answer (score 0):

List elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.RelativeLayout")) вернет список плашек

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.RelativeLayout.TextView[@index='0']")) - выбранный город
driver.findElement(By.xpath("android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.RelativeLayout.TextView[contains(text(), 'город')]"))
driver.findElement(By.xpath("android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.RelativeLayout.TextView[@index='2']")) - russia, moscow
driver.findElement(By.xpath("android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.RelativeLayout.TextView[@index='3']")) - 15km

Если не находит по id, то либо id  не верный, либо элементов с таким id несколько, но в разных элементах. Не помешал бы дамп экрана со скрином